# How calculate the end-to-end delay , Throughput in simulation script editor using Contiki 2.7 Cooja?

Tags: contiki

I'm trying to code the simulation script editor to calculate end-to-end delay and so on, but after the simulation is finished, I encounter the following message:

TEST TIMEOUT

TEST FAILED 
[if test was run without visualization, Cooja would now have been terminated]

If anyone can point me in the right direct, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: There are many ways. You need to do that in the C code, not in Cooja. Voting to close.

Comment: @kfx , hi .I have written code with C ,but I do not know how to enable it in cooja.